# Printing out linked list elements

Tags: c++, list, recursion

I wrote a program that adds elements recursively, and then prints out the elements. The problem is, that the program prints out only the first element in the list. I tried to solve this, but I don't know where is the problem...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct list
{
    int value;
    list* next;
};

list* addNewElement(list* p_head, int elems)
{
    if (elems >= 1)
    {
        list* p_list = new list;

        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> p_list->value;

        p_list->next = p_head;

        addNewElement(p_head, elems - 1);

        return p_list;
    }
}

void printList(list* p_head)
{
    list* p_cur = p_head;

    cout << "ELEMENTS: " << endl;

    while (p_cur != NULL)
    {
        cout << p_cur->value;
        p_cur = p_cur->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    list* p_head = NULL;

    int elemNR;

    cout << "Enter how many elements do you want in the list: ";
    cin >> elemNR;

    p_head = addNewElement(p_head, elemNR);

    cout << endl;

    printList(p_head);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE...";

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your `addNewElement()` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Side note: that loop belongs in `main()`; your linked list code should be managing *the list*; not the user input interaction. And you might ask yourself what happens when you actually reach `0` in your recursion? Ie. there is no return value and a decent compiler would have warned about that code path missing said-requirement.

Comment: Another issue -- What if the user enters 0 as the number of elements in the list?  An empty list is perfectly valid and reasonable, but your program will go into uncharted territory if 0 is entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that after all iterations You have a lot of list objects in which `next` pointer points to `NULL`. You should modify your `addNewElement` method to something like this:

```
list* addNewElement(list* p_head, int elems) {
    if (elems >= 1) {
        list* p_list = new list;

        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> p_list->value;

        p_list->next = addNewElement(p_head, elems - 1);
        return p_list;
    }
    return p_head;
}
```

What had changed? `p_list->next` pointer is being set to the beginning of next list's element instead of `NULL` ;)

EDIT: Here is working code: http://ideone.com/oJ8kX7